# Is it possible to have unsubscribe from parent business unit doesn't affect the child business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Is it possible to change the Parent BU Setting to "Subscribers will be unsubscribed from this business unit only"

Because If we have a parent and child Business Unit. If the Subscriber exists in both BU, the parent BU subscriber preference supersede their value in the child BU. and we can't send emails

And for me, I can see the parent business unit is having this setting "subscribers will be unsubscribed from all business units in the enterprise"

And I couldn't change anything here!

I would like to know is it possible to change it? How complex is this to change it?

And if not do you see any other way to surpass this and solve this issue?

I can only think of one solution, having a user-defined field for managing unsubscribes and adding them in all query to make sure we don't send emails to unsubscribers.

So the system field for unsubscribe status should always hold a value "Active"

Any advice here will be really helpful.

Answer (score 6):

This is the way Enterprise and Business Unit unsubscribes are designed to work - any unsubscribes at the Enterprise level will be honored at the Business Unit level, but unsubscribes at the Business Unit level don't necessarily need to be honored at the Enterprise level, it depends on how you set up the relationships in your Enterprise Business Unit Admin.

You can't send email at the Enterprise level without unsubscribes being affected at the Business Unit level. Even if you use publication lists at the Enterprise level, if someone were to reply "unsubscribe" or use their email client's unsubscribe function it still registers as a master unsubscribe which will opt them out of the Enterprise and your child Business Unit.

Since your problem is coming from a misunderstanding of how your Business Unit relationships are set up, your best options are to try to minimize the amount of Enterprise unsubscribes by using publication lists, or create a new child Business Unit for the mail you were expecting to be insulated from the other child Business Units, and make sure those unsubscribes are recorded at the BU level and not at the parent level.

I do not recommend trying to record opt-out status outside of All Subscribers. It invites a scenario where this user-generated status is not remembered and can email against someone's preferences.